# MySQL use JSON_CONTAINS with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, json, where-clause, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to make a subquery inside `JSON_CONTAINS` to have a results like this

```
SELECT * FROM addresses JSON_CONTAINS(`groups`, '"Client"', '$') ;
```

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM addresses JSON_CONTAINS(
    `groups`, 
    (SELECT u.group FROM users u WHERE u.email = 'example@email.org' LIMIT 1),
    '$'
) ;
```

But since the subquery returns `Client` instead of `"Client"` `JSON_CONTAINS` doesn't accept the value:

> ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_contains: "Invalid value." at position 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just concat the double quotes in the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM addresses 
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(
    `groups`, 
    (SELECT CONCAT('"', u.group, '"') FROM users u WHERE u.email = 'example@email.org' LIMIT 1),
);
```

Note that `$` is the default value for the third argument of `JSON_CONTAINS()`.

I am quite suspicious about the the subquery:

- don't you want to correlate it with the outer query?
- `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` might not behave consistently

Comment: Thanks for the answer! `don't you want to correlate it with the outer query?` I'm not sure what you mean. `LIMIT without ORDER BY might not behave consistently` since it's a `unique` field, it should be alright.